# Understanding the output of df -h command

Tags: command-line, partitioning, filesystem

I would like you to help me understand the output of `df -h` below:

```
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,7M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sda3       229G   68G  150G  32% /
tmpfs           7,9G  211M  7,6G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       84M   84M     0 100% /snap/core/3748
/dev/loop0      160M  160M     0 100% /snap/spotify/5
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           1,6G   68K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I would like to understand what exactly are the `udev`, `tmpfs` and `/dev/loop` partitions.

I am wondering if they are some sort of 'leftoveres' after my Virtual Machines in Virtual Box.

I had a few virtual machines with 8GB in size but I have removed them and I still see there are some partitions that are taking quite a lot of space.

- Are they related to Virtual Box?
- Is it safe to remove those partitions?

Comment: You can use `df -Th` to print file system type too

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/296038/what-is-the-difference-between-tmpfs-and-ramfs and https://askubuntu.com/questions/834093/small-snap-loop-devices-visible-in-gnome-disk-utility-or-what-is-the-function-of

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have only one actual partition `/dev/sda3`.

You should not touch the `udev` and `tmpfs` partitions.

- `tmpfs` is a virtual memory filesystem based on your RAM
- `udev` supplies Dynamic device management using *virtual files*

More info regarding `udev` and `tmpfs` you can find in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994357/accessing-other-drives-on-an-aws-ec2-instance/994372#994372).

- `/dev/loop` partitions are a mounted snap-file which is based on [SquashFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) read-only file system

You can check what is the content of `/snap/core/3748` and `/snap/spotify/5` folders.
Anyway - those are very small files (160M and 84M) - so removing them won't save much disk space.